# Transfer mysql binary log into select in CDC

Tags: java, mysql, regex

I would like to do a real time reading from mysql.
The idea is simple. I use the binary log to trigger the select statement.
Meanwhile I'd like to read only the new rows on every change.
And currently I just consider insert.

So when someone do

```
insert into sometable(uid,somecolumn) values(uid,something)
```

My code will be triggered and do

```
select from sometable where uid=uid
```

Of course I have already written down which columns are the primary key because it seems no information from binlog.

I cannot find a tool to analysis mysql insert statement. So I use the regex to find out which column equals which value, then extract primary keys.

BUT the real problems what will happen if I do

```
Insert into `table` (`col`) values (select 0 as `col` from `dummy`);
```

How can I find out the col=0?

Is it impossible that make a select statement that select the new changed rows, triggered by the insert statement?

Answer (score 0):

In a `TRIGGER`, you have access to the `OLD` and `NEW` values.  With them, you can write code (in the `TRIGGER`) to log, for example, just the changes.  Something like...

```
IF NEW.col1 != OLD.col1 THEN INSERT INTO LOG ...; END; 
IF NEW.col2 != OLD.col2 THEN INSERT INTO LOG ...; END;
```